# How can we reconcile Matthew 10:34 & John 16:33?

Tags: john, matthew

(KJV)Mathew 10:34-35

> 34 Think not that I am come to send **peace** on earth: I came not to send peace, but a sword. [35] For I am come to set a man at variance against his father, and the daughter against her mother, and the daughter in law against her mother in law.

(KJV)John 16:33

> 33 These things I have spoken unto you, that in me ye might have **peace**. In the world ye shall have tribulation: but be of good cheer; I have overcome the world.

The above texts seem to be at variance to each other,how can we reconcile them

Comment: There's nothing to reconcile. The second passage clearly states that *in the world ye shall have tribulation*, which is the same idea as the one expressed in the first passage. See also Luke 12:51-53. The fact that inner peace and worldly peace are not the same is clear from John 14:27 and 16:33. The same goes for the distinction between earthly and eternal life in Matthew 10:39, 16:25; Mark 8:35; Luke 9:24, 17:33; John 12:25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Do not suppose that I came to cast (βαλεῖν) peace over the earth. I did not come to cast (βαλεῖν) peace, but a sword. (Matthew 10:34 DLNT)*

The Disciples Literal New Testament accurately describes **how** Jesus was **not** going to bring peace. A meaning of the word βαλεῖν means to cast or throw **without caring where it falls**. [[906-ballo]](http://biblehub.com/greek/906.htm)

Jesus did not come to throw out peace without caring where it falls. Rather He came specifically that those who believe in His Name would have the peace He brought to the world:

> *“I leave you peace. I give you My peace. I do not give to you as the world gives. Do not let your heart be troubled, nor let it be afraid. (John 14:27 DLNT)*
>
> *“I have spoken these things to you in order that you may have peace in Me. You have affliction in the world, but take-courage— I have overcome the world”. (John 16:33 DLNT)*

In other words, His peace would be implanted one person at a time. The internal logic of Matthew 10:34 is that Jesus did not come to cast His peace without caring where it fell, rather He came to cast His sword (the Word) without caring where it fell.